# ¿Cómo cuento caracteres dentro de un mismo campo uno por uno?

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy tratando de contar los caracteres de un mismo campo uno por uno con el siguiente script (Puede estar equivocado):

```
SELECT micampo, length(micampo),(((length(micampo)-length(replace(micampo,';',''))))/length(';')+1)Cantidad
from mytable;
```

pero no puedo...

Quiero que se enumere de la siguiente manera:

Ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

| micampo | numero_character | Cantidad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| daniela | 7 | 1;2;3;4;5;6;7 |
| pedro | 5 | 1;2;3;4;5 |
| juan | 4 | 1;2;3;4 |
| pep | 3 | 1;2;3 |

Comment: Qué sentido tiene lo que pides, no entiendo, da más detalles

Comment: Quieres saber la cantidad de numeros o la longitud del texto sin los `;`?

Comment: sql no es para eso...

Comment: Ese ejercicio me lo colocaron en una prueba para optar como Ing. Junior pero no pude hacerla la idea es contar los caracteres de un campo ejemplo: la palabra "prueba" esta palabra tiene 6 caracteres y con la función length me imprime su cantidad que sería "6", pero también me pide sobre esa misma palabra "prueba",  , contar cada carácter y reemplazarlo por numero cuando imprima esta palabra debe quedar asi: "1;2;3;4;5;6", ¿alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Parece que tu código está haciendo lo contrario a lo que necesitas. Está contando el número de elementos de la cadena en vez de generar la cadena.

Para generar la cadena, necesitas 2 cosas: Saber como generar los números consecutivos y saber como concatenarlos. Para generarlos, podemos usar una tabla de números (tally en inglés) y para concatenarlos usamos la función `LISTAGG()`.

En este caso, estoy usando una tabla de números virtual que se genera en memoria. Esa tabla la uno usando un non-equi JOIN, que significa que no uso igual sino una comparación distinta.

```
WITH E(n) AS( SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION ALL 
              SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION ALL 
              SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION ALL 
              SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 1 FROM dual ),
cteTally AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.n) n
            FROM E a, E b)
SELECT micampo, 
       length(tab.micampo) AS numero_character,
       LISTAGG( tal.n, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY n) AS cantidad
from mytable tab
JOIN cteTally tal ON length(tab.micampo) >= tal.n
GROUP BY micampo;
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Luis Cazares por la retro alimentación !  en efecto tu código hizo lo que pedía la prueba, ahora me dedico a estudiarlo en detalle para entenderlo mucho mejor, de nuevo muchas gracias !

Comment: Ten en cuenta que es posible que hayan estado buscando como crearías una función para luego llamarla en tu consulta.